# Connection to spark and accessing hive table without thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, spark-thriftserver

I am writing a Java Spark application that needs to connect to hive and get some basic table info and query that table for data. I am creating a spark session and getting info like below. But this uses thrift server. I want to see if I can do the same without using thrift server. Is that possible and how do I do it? I am trying to write a JDBC client that that can connect to spark via sparkSQL to access hive tables but without using thrift server. Please provide your thoughts and suggestions on how to approach this. Thank you.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName(" Hive example")
              .enableHiveSupport()
              .getOrCreate();

           Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
              .format("jdbc")
               .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
              .option("url", " jdbc:hive2://host:port")
              .option("dbtable", "mytable")
              .option("fetchsize", "20")
              .load();
        df.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

With Spark 2 you can try something like this,

```
SparkSession ss = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName(" Hive example")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate();
```

Note the `hive.metastore.uris` property, change localhost to point to you sandbox or cluster.

one `ss` is initialised, you can read tables like below,

```
val df = ss.read.table("db_name.table_name")
```

JDBC way:

```
spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default")
    .option("dbtable", "clicks_json")
    .load()
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: But this is still using thrift server. I want to avoid using the thrift server. Is that possible? Not all platforms support thrift server.

Comment: there are two ways, either JDBC or thrift

Comment: ok, thanks. If you have any example of doing it with JDBC, please share. Thanks.

Comment: JDBC is what you've mentioned in your question. updating answer